# PHP "preg_match" to check whether the text contains small characters

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

If there are no lowercase letters in a string using **PHP** "**preg_match**", "*No lowercase letters!*" I want to print the warning.

Normally, there is no letter **" İ "** among the allowed characters. But the warning I want is not displayed.

---

**Desired Result:**

I want a warning displayed when there are different characters, except for those allowed.

---

**Allowable lowercase letter list;**

> **[a-z]**
>
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>
> **Extra Small Letters**
>
> ığüşöç

---

**My Faulty Code:**

```
    <?php
        $string = "THIS İS A TEST";
        
        if (!preg_match("/[a-zığüşöç]/",$string)){
            echo 'No lowercase letters!';
        }

        // Result: empty

    ?>
```

**Reply**

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zığüşöç]+$/",$string)){
    echo 'No lowercase letters!';
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. `$string` doesn't contain any of the letters in the prohibited list, so your code correctly reports it. If I add a prohibited letter it doesn't. Perhpas you just need to remove the `!` operator.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan It will give a warning since there is no lower case letter.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan allowed characters are available, but all are large. It should only give the warning when there is no lower case letter.

Comment: preg_match("/[a-zığüşöç]+$/",$string)